# Can't change mamp ports on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, port, mamp

I recently switched from xampp to mamp because of issues with xampp. I'm trying to change my ports on mamp but when I click `Set Web & MySQL ports to 80 & 3306` I get and error reading

`There is a problem with the server ports. Each server must be assigned a unique port. Please check your configuration.`

I am pretty sure the reason this is doing this is because of my uninstalled xampp. I've searched the web for a solution but can't find anything. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Port 80 is probably occupied ... netstat -ano | grep 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the nginx port. I set the Nginx port to 81 instead of 80 and it fixed it.